# Reporting Services formatting

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

Im currently developing av price list using SQL Reporting Services.

In that report I have a list which represents a item category, the list is connected to a datasource and is inceremented for each category in the database.

Inside the list I have a table which outputs all items within that category.

Everything is working as expected, first I show the category name and then all the items inside that category are listed. My problem is that sometimes there are so many products that it is using multiple pages. On the first page my category name is showing but on the next pages only the items are showing.

I want to show the category name again on the next page so that the user can see what category the items belong to without going back one page.

Does anyone know how to do this, point me in the right direction please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your report use a GROUP row and that Group should be a category.
Then highlight this row in reporting services and look at the properties section.
One of the properties is: "RepeatOnNewPage" set this to true and you will see this Category on subsequent pages now.

Here is a sample for you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, got it working! My category title was in a text box inside the list. 

Created a grouping row as you said and then pasted the category title in the table header. 

After that I did set RepeatOnNewPage = true

Now everything i perfect, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working.  I was working on reports today so you caught me at a good time :).